# Laravel - eloquent: prepare insert method in model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I work with laravel 5.3 with eloquent relations engine.

In my controllers I have methods that are inserting data to several related tables. This method is repeated in few places.

```
TradePartnerData::create([
    'trade_partner_data_type' => $dataType,
    'trade_partner_id' => $id,
    'value' => $value
]);
```

I wish to optimize that and I wonder If I could prepare method in my model that takes task of inserting data to database?

```
/*method in controller that I want*/
$model = new TradePartnerData();
$model->makeSpecialInsert($dataType, $id, $value)
```

Then in controller I only have to call the model method with proper parameters without writing any model's keys.

For now, I just keep in my models eloquent's relations between tables.
So the question is, how to prepare insert method in model so that I could use:

`$model->makeSpecialInsert($dataType, $id, $value)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it in multiple controllers like that, sounds like you might want to set up a parent controller class structure to make things easier.  That said, here is something you can toss into a model:

```
public static function quickSave($dataType, $id, $value)
{
  return \App\TradePartnerData::firstOrCreate(
    ['trade_partner_data_type' => $dataType],
    ['trade_partner_id' => $id],
    ['value' => $value]
  );
}
```

And the call:

```
  $model = TradePartnerData::quickSave($dataType, $id, $value);
```